# Automatically create snapshot before launching VirtualBox VM?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, script, shell-script, snapshot

Does anyone have a script or know how to write one to automatically take a snapshot of a VM before launching it for use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your running windows placing this text into a .bat file should do the trick:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox
VBoxManage snapshot "Virtual Name" take "Snapshot Name"
VBoxManage startvm "Virtual Name"
```

If your running a *NIX you will have to change this to something like

```
VBoxManage snapshot "Virtual Name" take "Snapshot Name"
VBoxManage startvm "Virtual Name"
```

As you wont need to change your directory to access the VBoxManage command and save it to a .sh file, change the attribute to executable and then invoke it to run it.

Answer (score 0):

probably you don't need this anymore, but in case someone will have the same problem, I created a simple script to automatically snapshot my virtual machines.

GitHub: https://github.com/Meru3m/virtualbox-snapshotter

Answer (score 0):

I made my own version of backup if someone need it

Regards

https://github.com/nktrabajo/bashbackups